# CSS Grid will not format correctly no matter what

Tags: html, css, sass

I am following a series of Traversy Media videos for creating a portfolio website. I have a foundational knowledge of HTML/CSS. We have to create a grid and no matter what I do, I cannot get the grid to show up in my browser (Chrome). The grid will be for the About info on the about page. Also the footer isn't showing up for some reason. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the about.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/31d2c226f4.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
    <title>About Me</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="overlay"></div>
    <header> 
        <div class="menu-btn">
            <div class="btn-line"></div>
            <div class="btn-line"></div>
            <div class="btn-line"></div>
        </div>

        <nav class="menu">
            <div class="menu-branding">
                <div class="portrait"></div>
            </div>
            <ul class="menu-nav">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="/" class="nav-link">
                    Home
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item current">
                    <a href="about.html" class="nav-link">
                    About Moi
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="work.html" class="nav-link">
                    My Work
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="Contact.html" class="nav-link">
                    How to Reach Me
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>

    <main id="about">
        <h1 class="lg-heading">
            About 
            <span class="text-secondary">Me</span>
        </h1>
        <h2 class="sm-heading">
            Let me tell you a few things...
        </h2>
        <div class="about-info">
            <!-- <img src="img/portrait.jpeg" alt="Alex Gool" class="bio-image"> -->

            <div class="bio">
                <h3 class="text-secondary">BIO</h3>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Exercitationem dolore at, quasi natus veritatis, amet cum voluptates, iste fugit atque autem laboriosam. Provident officia modi inventore fugit recusandae vitae nisi.</p>
            </div>

            <div class="job job-1">
                <h3>123 Webshop</h3>
                <h6>Full Stack Developer</h6>
                <p>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nisi ipsum aperiam inventore. Inventore illo accusamus debitis facilis, quisquam velit aliquam?</p>
            </div>

            <div class="job job-2">
                <h3>Designers ABC</h3>
                <h6>Front End Developer</h6>
                <p>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nisi ipsum aperiam inventore. Inventore illo accusamus debitis facilis, quisquam velit aliquam?</p>
            </div>

            <div class="job job-3">
                <h3>Webworks</h3>
                <h6>Graphic Designer</h6>
                <p>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nisi ipsum aperiam inventore. Inventore illo accusamus debitis facilis, quisquam velit aliquam?</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        
    </main>

    <footer id="main-footer">
        Copyright &copy; 2021
    </footer>

<script src="js/main.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

And here is the main SCSS file

```
// Move variable and functions to _config.scss file. This helps tidy up the main.scss file and makes the code more readable. Use @import then the file name (NOT WITH THE .scss EXTENSION).
@import "config";
@import "menu";

// Ensures inside padding will not affect height/width of box, it will just be in the box itself.
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  @include background;
  background: $primary-color;
  color: set-text-color($primary-color);
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: "Segoe UI", "Segoe UI", Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
  line-height: 1.5;
}

// Headings
h1,
h2,
h3 {
  margin: 0;
  font-weight: 400;
  &.lg-heading {
    font-size: 6rem;
  }

  &.sm-heading {
    margin-bottom: 2rem;
    padding: 0.2rem 1rem;
    // Background to heading information will be lighter.
    // Wrap in RGBA function, 0.5 is the opacity.
    background: rgba(lighten($primary-color, 2), 0.5);
  }
}

a {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}

// Header (icon) is fixed so it stays at top right when user scrolls through the webpage.
header {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 2;
  width: 100%;
}

.text-secondary {
  color: $secondary-color;
}

// Nesting the .icons class so that only the icons in the main tag will be affected. This is specific to SASS.
main {
  padding: 4rem;
  // height: 100%;
  min-height: calc(100vh - 60px);

  .icons {
    margin-top: 1rem;
    color: set-text-color($primary-color);
    // Inside the div class "icons", each icon is wrapped in a link.
    a {
      padding: 0.4rem;

      // Putting the & in things is specific to SASS, this is not a feature of normal CSS.
      &:hover {
        color: $secondary-color;
        @include easeOut();
      }
    }
  }

  &#home {
    // This makes it so that there will never be scroll bars.
    overflow: hidden;
    h1 {
      // This brings my name down closer to the middle of the page.
      margin-top: 20vh;
    }
  }
}

.about-info {
  display: grid !important;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr !important;
  grid-template-rows: auto !important;
  grid-template-areas:
    "bioimage bio bio"
    " job1 job2 job3" !important;

  .bio-image {
    grid-area: bioimage;
    margin: auto;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: $secondary-color 3px solid;
  }

  .bio {
    grid-area: bio;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
  }

  .job-1 {
    grid-area: job1;
  }
  .job-2 {
    grid-area: job2;
  }
  .job-3 {
    grid-area: job3;
  }

  .job {
    background: lighten($primary-color: 5);
    padding: 0.5rem;
    border-bottom: $secondary-color 5px solid;
  }
}

#main-footer {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 1rem;
  background: darken($primary-color: 10);
  color: set-text-color($primary-color);
  height: 60px;
}

@import "mobile";
```

Answer (score 0):

I took this snippet from the code you linked and rewrote it without SCSS so it can compile below. It seems to me like display: grid is working just fine. If you open the chrome dev tools and inspect, you will see a "grid" label on the .about-info element.

```css
.about-info {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: auto;
  grid-template-areas: "bioimage bio bio" " job1 job2 job3" !important;
}

.about-info .job-1 {
  grid-area: job1;
}

.about-info .job-2 {
  grid-area: job2;
}

.about-info .job-3 {
  grid-area: job3;
}

.about-info .bio {
  grid-area: bio;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}

.about-info .bio-image {
  grid-area: bioimage;
  margin: auto;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: $secondary-color 3px solid;
}

.about-info .job {
  background: lighten($primary-color: 5);
  padding: 0.5rem;
  border-bottom: $secondary-color 5px solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="about-info">

  <div class="bio">
    <h3 class="text-secondary">BIO</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Exercitationem dolore at, quasi natus veritatis, amet cum voluptates, iste fugit atque autem laboriosam. Provident officia modi inventore fugit recusandae vitae nisi.</p>
  </div>

  <div class="job job-1">
    <h3>123 Webshop</h3>
    <h6>Full Stack Developer</h6>
    <p>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nisi ipsum aperiam inventore. Inventore illo accusamus debitis facilis, quisquam velit aliquam?</p>
  </div>

  <div class="job job-2">
    <h3>Designers ABC</h3>
    <h6>Front End Developer</h6>
    <p>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nisi ipsum aperiam inventore. Inventore illo accusamus debitis facilis, quisquam velit aliquam?</p>
  </div>

  <div class="job job-3">
    <h3>Webworks</h3>
    <h6>Graphic Designer</h6>
    <p>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nisi ipsum aperiam inventore. Inventore illo accusamus debitis facilis, quisquam velit aliquam?</p>
  </div>
</div>
```